# Starting a process hangs the main process even using threading

Tags: .net, multithreading, process, c++-cli, freeze

I'm trying to run other processes, let's assume `ChildProcess.exe`, from my main application `Main.exe` and I expect no hanging since I'm not trying to catch the output, only shell execute. But somehow, my `Main.exe` hangs in some conditions. Both executables have .NET forms but this problem occurs before trying to reach window handles. Basicly what I do is something like below.

Main.exe

This is how I create a new thread for process executing code

```
...
ThreadStart^ threadStart = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::CreateNewProcessThread);
Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(threadStart);
thread->Start();
...
```

Here is the thread function

```
System::Void MyForm::CreateNewProcessThread() {
    String^ ApplicationPath = Application::ExecutablePath->Substring(0, Application::ExecutablePath->LastIndexOf("\\"));
    ...
    Process^ p = gcnew Process();
    p->StartInfo->FileName = ApplicationPath + "\\ChildProcess.exe";
    p->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = true;
    p->StartInfo->RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    p->StartInfo->RedirectStandardError = false;
    p->Start();
    ...
}
```

ChildProcess is nothing special. You can try an empty form application, it doesn't matter. When I try to run multiple processes at the same time, my main application starts hanging. It doesn't hang forever like a deadlock. It just hangs for less than 1 seconds but it still hangs at the first process execution. When `ChildProcess.exe` is started (completely loaded) once, `Main.exe` is not affected afterwards. But if we put an infinite loop to the `Form_Load` event like "while(1);" and try to execute a few processes at the same time (like 3 or 4 nothing more), `Main.exe` is almost completely locked up.

This might be caused by the `STAThread` structure but since I'm using `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, this looks like a must.

What I don't get it is, if I put and infinite loop to my thread (`MyForm::CreateNewProcessThread()`), my application is not affected by this infinite loop at all since it is a seperate thread. But when I try to start a process from that thread, my whole application including my main thread is affected.

I have two questions on this problem.

1) What is the reason?

2) What is the solution?

P.S: I checked similar threads on stackoverflow and none of them provided a real explanation or real solution. Please don't give me links the other stackoverflow questions. I've already checked them all.

Comment: The reason is not visible in your snippet.  Starting a process does *not* require starting a thread, it normally takes no more than 50 milliseconds.  So presumably you are using the thread for other reasons, the kind of reasons that *could* explain the delays.

Comment: what if i want to execute 50 processes at the same time? should i wait 2.5 seconds? i had many threading problems with a 3rd party library because of too many static usages and I had to use multi-processing instead of multi-threading. At this point, my main application should be able to run fluently without any hanging problems. but multi-processing caused hanging as well unexpectedly. What I need is, even if I execute 100 processes, if hardware is capable enough to run these, my application should not affected by them.

Comment: At the moment 3 or 4 processes can lock my main application if they are locked, too. But other processes, let's say an Internet Explorer window, is not affected by them. So, OS is working without a problem but my application is the only one affected by those processes. What I want is to be able to execute other processes like i have no relation with them. This should be possible using native Win32 functions but the problem is, I will need the main window handle later. But this problem occurs even if I don't do anything after process->Start();

Comment: `But if we put an infinite loop to the Form_Load event like "while(1);" and try to execute a few processes at the same time (like 3 or 4 nothing more), Main.exe is almost completely locked up.` An infinite loop at the Form_Load would certainly lock up your Main.exe

Comment: I have no time to verify that.  You can try setting `UseShellExecute` to false.  If you set `UseShellExecute` to true, it means using the Windows Shell to launch the process.  I could imagine there might be some inter-process communication going on.  Your main process hangs should be due to some sort of synchronous access to the Windows Shell.

Comment: `An infinite loop at the Form_Load would certainly lock up your Main.exe` I'm talking about the ChildProcess.exe's Form_Load event, not Main.exe's. Even if ChildProcess.exe turns into not responding state, I expect Main.exe to run without a problem since they are seperate processes. That's the problem here. And trying UseShellExecute=false doesn't work (i tried of course) and it actually can hang the Main.exe since it tries to catch the process output that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a "managed" way to solve my problem. So I used Win32 API (`CreateProcess()`, `FindWindow()`, `WaitForInputIdle()`, `EnumThreadWindows()` etc.). Now it's working without hanging but I still don't know what's wrong with .NET's Process class.